# set background for indeterminate circular progress bar

Tags: android

I've a circular progress bar similar to the following and I'd like to add a static light blue background to the spinner.

What's the easiest way to do that?

I am new to Android development and often found it unexpectedly difficult to change little things.

http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-tqB3UP6KYaM/VItDu0F9kdI/AAAAAAAAATs/QB0X4AqWWY0/s1600/spinningwheel.gif

I've tried the following, but it would show an entire square of light blue.

spinner.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue_super_light));

Your help is greatly appreciated! 
Hui

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to do that by setting attributes, so I ended up creating a circle drawable and set it as the background.

```
            android:background="@drawable/circular_progress_bar_background"
```